# Php text game project: flashing dash

Tags: php

I think this is probably a fairly original question. I'm new to php, and as practice to get comfortable with the language, Im working on a terminal like "hacker vs security" game. It's a pretty easy layout, and I'm looking forward to the possibilities, but I'd like to echo a dash (-) that flashes in front the "command line." Is this even possible: here is my current attempt:

```
    <?php
    $dash = "-";
    $space = " ";
    $int = 1;


    if ($odd == $int % 2)
    {
    $od_ev = 2;
    $int++;
    }
    else
    {
    $od_ev =3;
    $int++;
    }


    while ($od_ev == 2)
    {
    echo $dash;
    }

    ?>
```

Edit: a while, else capability in php would work nicely here, allowing an:

```
    else
    {
    Echo $space
    }
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, normally the script being entirely parsed before any output is handled to the user. You'll want to implement this in javascript, as client code.

Comment: `<blink>-</blink>`... and if you'll excuse me now, I've got to go jump off a bridge somewhere now

Comment: Ah ok. Time to learn another language!

Comment: @MarcB You're lucky comments aren't downvotable!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use PHP CLI the following should work:

Output a `"\r"` after your dash/space so that the cursor will be set to the start of the line and overwrites the last output.
And you should use the following code or something similar:

```
<?php
$char[0] = "-";
$char[1] = " ";
$int = 1;

while(1){
    $c = $int % 2;
    echo $char[c] . "\r";
    $int++;
    sleep(100); //that the user has a chance to see the flashing, time to wait in milliseconds
}
```

Your code would just set $od_ev to 3 and increase $int by one and then stop.